# Github actions shell, how to transform a variable given as an output by a step into an array?

Tags: bash, shell, github, github-actions

The step outputs the following JSON: `["name1","name"]`. How can I convert it into an array so I can effectively use it as an array? I need to loop through it so I can use each value.

Parentheses don't work in GitHub Actions. I've tried to play around with `toJSON` and `fromJSON`. I've tried using `jq`. Nothing has worked so far. I haven't found anything online that works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). It is [preinstalled](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software) on GitHub runners.

Example ([live](https://jqplay.org/s/xjL4YNBfcV8)):

```bash
JSON='["name1","name"]'
ARRAY=$(echo "$JSON" | jq -r '.[]')
for NAME in $ARRAY; do echo $NAME; done
name1
name
```